# Theme.Dialog creates too small screen

Tags: android, themes

I have an activity with ListView that has:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

in Manifest.
When I open it and when it has only one line in ListView, the window that opens is very small.
How do I make the window take the whole screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this in your onCreate method of the Activity to make it full screen.

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.myxml);

    LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes(); 
            params.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            params.width  = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
           getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
   }
```

Comment: Solution do not work. Maybe it's because of the Dialog Theme with the ListView? Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks! My Activity (made to look like a dialog via the Manifest) had a fairly complicated LinearLayout and was displaying it just a few letters wide.  But wow, it worked for me!  But why?

Comment: Please check comments below for changes. The answer is over two years old and may require some edits.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that setting the window size does work, but you have to do it a bit later. In this example the window width is set to 90% of the display width, and it is done in `onStart()` rather than `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   // In order to not be too narrow, set the window size based on the screen resolution:
   final int screen_width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
   final int new_window_width = screen_width * 90 / 100; 
   LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
   layout.width = Math.max(layout.width, new_window_width); 
   getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer from PravinCG but it can be done with one line in onCreate()...

```
getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Comment: Solution do not work. Maybe it's because of the Dialog Theme with the ListView? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the suggested code before setcontentview() call. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small update. Used MATCH_PARENT instead of the deprecated FILL_PARENT. PravinCG's answer worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yeezz ! I figured it out ! The problem is that the margin sizes are not calculated in the window widht. So If you set the layout margin to 0 and move that part to the padding of the layout the problem will be solved.